# Присвоить массиву 2 значения массива 1, но с удаленным первым элементом

Tags: c#

Вот пример кода:

```
int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] b = new int[a.Length-1];
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    b[i] = a[i + 1];
}
```

Можно ли уменьшить его до одной строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно 1 строчкой, используя `System.Linq`:

```cs
int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] b = a.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Либо статическим методом `Array.Copy`:

```cs
int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] b = new int[a.Length-1];
Array.Copy(a, 1, b, 0, b.Length);
```

Comment: good decision bro

Comment: @polsok "solution"

Comment: @aepot um, thanks